# How to flatten nested references into a simple target?

Tags: mapstruct

I am using spring data jdbc with MapStruct. The POJOs are aligned with the table structure with all "internal-only" data like surrogate keys, audit information etc while the Domain object is hierarchical and contains only business relevant data.
I have to map between a table specific POJO (flat structure) and a Domain object with nested objects. How can I best do this with MapStruct 1.2.0 ?

```
// Pojo for table
public class PersonsRecord {
    @Id
    private Integer surrogateKey; // should not be mapped

    private String loginId;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp memberSince;

    // address columns
    private Integer houseNumber;
    private String addressStreet;
    private String addressCity;
    private String country;

    // getters and setters
}

// Domain object
public class PersonDto {
    private String loginId;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp memberSince;

    private Address address;
}

@Mapper(uses = MapperUtils.class)
public interface PersonMapper {

    PersonDto toPersonDto(PersonRecord person);

    Address toAddress(PersonRecord person);
}
```

The generated code for the `toPersonDto` ignores the `Address` and does not call the `toAddress` method like `MapStruct` reference mentions. May be because both methods takes the same input type? The generated code for `toAddress` looks good. Just that it is not automatically wired by `MapStruct` generation.

The reverse mapping generation is similar. No automatic call.

Is there a way to make this automatic (without custom methods, or decorators etc) ? I have similar pattern in many places.

Note : The `MapperUtils` is used for instantiating DTOs with immutable fields.

**Update:** I used the answer by Filip for mapping from `PersonRecord` to `PersonDto` including the `Person.Address`. For the reverse mapping I did the following:

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperUtils.class)
public abstract class PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "address", source = "person")
    public abstract PersonDto toPersonDto(PersonRecord person);

    protected abstract Address toAddress(PersonRecord person);

    public abstract PersonRecord toRecord(PersonDto dto);

    public abstract void updateAddress(PersonDto dto, @MappingTarget PersonRecord person);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void updateAddress(PersonDto dto, @MappingTarget PersonRecord record) {
        updateAddress(dto, record);
    }
}
```

That worked without issues. Thanks Filip for providing the direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the `toAddress` method is not picked up is that MapStruct doesn't know that it needs to map the `toPersonDto` parameter to the `PersonDto.address`. You are also most likely getting a warning that the address is not mapped.

In order to do the mapping you need to tell MapStruct how to map the `address`. You can do that by using `@Mapping`. Your mapper will then look like

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperUtils.class)
public interface PersonMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "address", source = "person")
    PersonDto toPersonDto(PersonRecord person);

    Address toAddress(PersonRecord person);
}
```

**Update** I forgot to add how to perform the reverse.

One way to perform the reverse mapping would be with custom `@Mapping` annotation, you will have to do this for each entry in `Address`. This is a bit cumbersome. There is an open Pull Request for MapStruct to allow this mapping to be done more easily. The PR is [mapstruct/mapstruct#1686](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1686).

Another way would be to use multi source parameter mapping. This can look like:

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperUtils.class)
public interface PersonRecordMapper {

    default PersonRecord toPersonRecord(PersonDto personDto) {
        if (personDto == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return toPersonRecord(personDto, personDto.getAddress());
    }

    @Mapping(target = "surrogateKey", ignore = true)
    PersonRecord toPersonRecord(PersonDto personDto, Address address);

}
```

This is going to work without manual `@Mapping` if and only if the names properties in the `Address` match the ones in `PersonRecord`. Otherwise you will still need to define `@Mapping`.

Comment: Thanks Filip. That solves the problem one way. On the reverse mapping is there a similar simple way to map both `person` and `person.address` to the same target ? Some of my DTOs have over a dozen fields. May be a custom method with a subsequent update call is better than specifying all the mappings explicitly. Or a decorator / delegate serving the same purpose..

Comment: You just changed your question. Have I known I would have immediately answered the second part. Can you please ask a second question for the reverse part?

Comment: Hi Filip. Not sure how this works here. I did mention about the same issue with the reverse mapping as well. May be it was not obvious enough. Do I update the question above or should i create a new question altogether ?

Comment: I just saw about the reverse, sorry. I will update me question appropriately

Comment: Your solution is simpler Filip. One method less. Thanks.

Comment: Doing an update method also has different semantics than doing a normal mapping. With update you can control how is it done, are values that don't exists set to null, default or just ignored, with normal mapping you can't do that

Comment: In the first code block should the second `@Mapper` actually be `@Mapping`?

Comment: You are right, it should be `@Mapping`. I fixed it, thanks for the info