# (Java, MapStruct) Is it possible to map fields from a nested object to an extended target object that shares a common base class?

Tags: java, mapstruct

So, I have a lilttle bit of a conundrum. I know these class names might be a little confusing, apologies.

Let’s say these are the objects I’m working with:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class EntityPO {
        private String firstName
        private String businessName;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AIOwner {
      private String firstName;
        private String name1;
}
```

```
public class AICoBorrower extends AIOwner {
        // blank for clarity 
}
```

```
public class CoBorrowerPO {
        //this class itself does not contain firstName or name1/businessName fields.
        protected EntityPO entity;
}
```

and I have  a mapper that basically maps `entityPO` & `aiowner`.

test:

```
@Test
  public void coBorrowerMappingTest() {

    CoBorrowerPO coPO = srp.makeCoBorrowerPO();
    //map to ai
    AICoBorrower coAI = AICoBorrowerMapper.INSTANCE.toAICoBorrower(coPO);
    //assert all fields
    assertEquals(coPO.getEntity().getFirstName(), coAI.getFirstName());

  }
```

mapper code:

```
@Mapper(uses = { AIPhoneMapper.class, AIAddressMapper.class })
public interface AIOwnerMapper {
  AIOwnerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AIOwnerMapper.class);

  @Mapping(target = "name1", source = "businessName")
  AIOwner toAIOwner(EntityPO entityPO);

  @InheritInverseConfiguration
  EntityPO toEntityPO(AIOwner aiOwner);

}
```

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, uses = { AIOwnerMapper.class })
public interface AICoBorrowerMapper extends AIOwnerMapper {
  AICoBorrowerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AICoBorrowerMapper.class);

  AICoBorrower toAICoBorrower(CoBorrowerPO coBorrower);

  @AfterMapping
  default AICoBorrower afterMapping(CoBorrowerPO coBorrowerPO) {
    if (coBorrowerPO == null) {
      return null;
    }

    AICoBorrower aiCoBorrower = new AICoBorrower();
    AIOwner aiOwner = AIOwnerMapper.INSTANCE.toAIOwner(coBorrowerPO.getEntity());
    aiCoBorrower.setName1(aiOwner.getName1());
    aiCoBorrower.setFirstName(aiOwner.getFirstName());

    return aiCoBorrower;
  }
}
```

My requirements involve using MapStruct to map fields from the `EntityPO` class to the base class `AICoBorrower`. Within the `CoBorrowerPO` class, there is a nested `EntityPO` object.

I wish to map `EntityPO` fields’ values directly to the `AICoBorrower`class field values, which extends the `AIOwner`class so it inherited those fields from aiOwner.

To achieve this, the existing `AIOwnerMapper` that i already have is needed to be used, which maps fields from `EntityPO` to `aiowner`. it does this successfully for the fields i wish to map. The issue lies in the extension of the functionality to `AICoBorrower` that also extends `AIOwner`. The desired outcome is to map fields from the nested `entityPO` directly to `AICoBorrower`, not through an additional class/object layer. `AICoBorrower`does not contain an `AIOwner`, it **is** the `AIOwner`.

⚠️***NOTE***⚠️:

*I want to avoid writing duplicate code in the field mappings (`@Mapping`) across multiple mappers that extend a common base mapper (**`AIOwnerMapper`** in this case). This way, any changes to the mappings in the base mapper will automatically apply to all the child mappers.*

I should also mention that this code I wrote works as it is. But i would prefer to not have to do all of the setters myself for this case, as that is what i am using mapstruct for. And imagine i have 3 of these objects that extend `AIOwner` and have the same behavior where the `entityPO` inside of the mirror object  should actually map the fields directly onto the AI object, not in a separate class/object layer.

as mentioned before, the code I have works, but I have to write code manually. I would preferrably *AVOID *something like this:

```
    @Mapping(source = "entityPO.field1", target = "field1") // Map fields from EntityPO to AICoborrower
    @Mapping(source = "entityPO.field2", target = "field2")
    // Add other fields as needed
    AICoborrower map(CoborrowerPO coborrowerPO);
```

If I can, I would like to not use `.`s because the field names are subject to change and I want all objects that extend AIOwner to have their own mapper that recognizes the changes to the AIOwnerMapper.

###### These tickets are the closest to what I am looking for, but I have not found a solution following them:

[mapstruct - map object with nested list to flat list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430184/mapstruct-map-object-with-nested-list-to-flat-list)

[How to flatten nested references into a simple target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580824/how-to-flatten-nested-references-into-a-simple-target)

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful answer if you slim down your question. You could start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have provided classes, mappers, and a runnable test. I could also edit the code to group my code so that it makes more sense as a whole. Would a visual diagram be helpful? I could draw one up. This is rather hard to describe. 